# Getting started with Swing?

Tags: java, swing, open-source

I'm new to Swing programming and would like to find an Open Source Swing poject that can help me get up to speed.  Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Before jumping in and trying to understand a project, why not go through the Sun Java tutorial and get some understanding of Swing, then start to do some small projects on your own. Once you are familiar with the framework then you would be able to better understand some open-source projects, IMO.

I haven't looked at the code, but this could be an enjoyable project to help with:
http://ostatic.com/croftsoft

Comment: +1 for Java Tutorial.  Swing is rather complex.

Answer (score 1):

How about [OpenSwing](http://oswing.sourceforge.net/)?

> OpenSwing is an open-source suite of advanced graphics components based on Swing toolkit: these components are more sophisticated than those provided with Swing and can be manipulated directly inside the UI designer of the IDE.
>
> It is also a framework that provides data binding mechanism between components and data model, based on the MVC paradigm. Data model is based on Java Beans (POJOs) and it is supported in all OpenSwing components, such as grid control, tree control or generic controls container.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: @Seki While this is true, as the above answer points out, JP could have easily added some explanation as to what the project deals with, where to start with the project, etc. A link-only answer can *always* be expanded to a better answer with some explanation as to what the link is to.

Comment: @Seki Your edit is what this post was missing. While simple links can be useful, I think you would agree this is at least a little more advantageous. The point of "Recommending for Deletion" is to bring the OP to attention so they know that their answer is lacking information. It also brings attention to other reviewers who might come in and edit the question much in the way you did. Thank you for the edit.

Comment: @Jon: Thanks, I agree. Think about removing your low-quality warning to prevent the deletion of the answer :)